# Effects on Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to do something like at this image, the main content goes up when I select another thing at the menu.
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4D8H.gif]

I know at a certain way how to do this, I'm using the same concept of a website with tabs, something like this:

```
$(function(){
                $("#content:First").show();
                $("#wrap a").click(function(){
                    $(".aba").hide();
                    var div = $(this).attr('href');
                    $(div).fadeIn('slow');
                    $('#menu li').css('background', '#03c0f3'); 
                    $(this).parent('li').css('background', '#2ADAF1');

                    return false;
                });
```

I want to know what is the effect that I can apply to div(on the $(div).) to become like this, or if there is some better way to do this.

Comment: Are you opposed to creating scrollable content and simply sliding to anchors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @d3c0y's idea why not make it a scrollable content and just slide to the contents on `click()`.

```
$('nav a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var div = $(this).attr('href'),
        //get the contents offset top position
        offsetTop = $(div).offset().top;
    //animate scrolling to the contents
    $('body, html').animate({
        scrollTop: offsetTop
    }, 'slow');
});
```

You can also apply some fading effects using `fadeTo()`:

```
$(div).fadeTo('slow', 1).siblings().fadeTo('slow', 0);
```

You can also remove the scrollbar if you like to `body {overflow:hidden;}`, the scrolling/anchoring will still work.

See this [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/pJCGW/).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any predefined function suiting your needs. You'd have to construct it by yourself using [.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/). It should look something like this:

```
$('#navigation a').click(function(){
    $('#content').css({
        position : 'absolute',
        top : 0,
        left : 0
    }).animate({
        top : -$('#content').height() - 1
    }, 250, function(){
        // Change content here
        // Animate it back
    });
});
```

Alternatively, what many other sites are using, you can deliver your entire content in a single page and scroll respectively ([example](http://www.hide.io/)). For that, have a look at different plugins, such as [this one](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/).